# Maintaining the underlying value of a TableColumn but displaying something else, for sorting purposes

Tags: java, javafx-8

Relevant extract from the FXML:

```
    <TableView fx:id="events">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="eventTime" text="Time"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="eventType" text="Event type"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="eventRule" text="Matcher"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="eventIndex" text="Index"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="eventDepth" text="Depth"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="eventPath" text="Matcher path"/>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
```

The `eventTime` column is defined as:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<TraceEvent, Long> eventTime;
```

I bind the property as such:

```
public DefaultTraceTabView(final TraceTabUi ui)
{
    this.ui = ui;
    bindColumn(ui.eventTime, "nanoseconds");
    // other non relevant code
}

//

private static <T> void bindColumn(final TableColumn<TraceEvent, T> column,
    final String propertyName)
{
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(propertyName));
}
```

OK, this works; I can sort the column, but the display is... Well... Nanoseconds.

And what I'd like to display in the column, instead of for instance `98343420`, is `98 ms, 343.420 μs`. But keep the sort order defined for the property...

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You can sort any way you want by setting a table column comparator.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#comparatorProperty--  I'll dig up some old code if you have problems.

Comment: @brian I don't need a custom comparator; the builtin sorting for `Long` works just fine. What I want to do is update the display text in the cell all the while keeping the "underlying" value.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to self...

Found the solution on [this link](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-tableview-cell-renderer/):

```
    ui.eventTime.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<TraceEvent, Long>()
    {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final Long item, final boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            setText(empty ? null : nanosToText(item));
        }
    });
```

and `nanosToText()` is a method which does what its name says.